# How to cast List<dynamic> to List<String>?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a record class to parse objects coming from Firestore.  A stripped down version of my class looks like:

```dart
class BusinessRecord {
  BusinessRecord.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference})
      : assert(map['name'] != null),
        name = map['name'] as String,
        categories = map['categories'] as List<String>;

  BusinessRecord.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(snapshot.data, reference: snapshot.reference);

  final String name;
  final DocumentReference reference;
  final List<String> categories;
}
```

This compiles fine, but when it runs I get a runtime error:

`type List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' in type cast`

If I just use `categories = map['categories'];` I get a compile error: `The initializer type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the field type 'List<String>'`.

`categories` on my Firestore object is a List of strings. How do I properly cast this?

Edit: Following is what the exception looks like when I use the code that actually compiles:

[image: VSCode Exception]

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Imho, you shouldn't cast the list, instead cast its children one by one, for example:

**UPDATE**

```
...
...
categories = (map['categories'] as List)?.map((item) => item as String)?.toList();
...
...
```

[image]

Comment: If I try `categories = map['categories'].map((category) => category as String);` I get `The initializer type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the field type 'List<String>'`.

If I try `categories = (map['categories'] as List<dynamic>).map((category) => category as String);` I get `The initializer type 'Iterable<String>' can't be assigned to the field type 'List<String>'`.

Comment: Both of those are compile-time errors - there is no stack trace. I've updated the question with a screenshot of the exception in VSCode when the compileable code runs though.

Comment: Thanks! Your updated example worked great. One modification I had to add (likely because I'm using https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/analysis_options.yaml) was specifying `dynamic` for the type of `List` and `item`: `categories = (map['categories'] as List<dynamic>)?.map((dynamic item) => item as String)?.toList();`. Also sorry for the delay in responding - I was on vacation for 2 weeks.

Comment: Will that still work if your item List is empty ?

Answer (score 54):

Easier answer and as far as I am aware also the suggested way.

```dart
List<String> categoriesList = List<String>.from(map['categories'] as List);
```

**Note the "as List" is probably not even needed.**

Comment: Just wanna add to this if anyone's map might have a null value  --- >>> 

          List<String>.from(map["categories"] ??= [])

<<--- in my case when added a new field to a firebase document the previous documents didn't have the categories so were null.

Comment: Can we have a [mre] to proove that it is actually not needed instead of probably not needed?

Answer (score 19):

**Easy Answer:**

You can use the spread operator, like `[...json["data"]]`.

**Full example:**

```
final Map<dynamic, dynamic> json = {
  "name": "alice",
  "data": ["foo", "bar", "baz"],
};

// method 1, cast while mapping:
final data1 = (json["data"] as List)?.map((e) => e as String)?.toList();
print("method 1 prints: $data1");

// method 2, use spread operator:
final data2 = [...json["data"]];
print("method 2 prints: $data2");
```

Output:

```
flutter: method 1 prints: [foo, bar, baz]
flutter: method 2 prints: [foo, bar, baz]
```

Answer (score 15):

Just to put this out there, if you want to cast `dynamic` to `String`:

```dart
List dynamiclist = ['hello', 'world'];

List<String> strlist = dynamiclist.cast<String>();
```

Comment: unclear why this isn't the top answer...

Answer (score 4):

`final list = List<String>.from(await value.get("paymentCycle"));`

I have use this when i am getting data from Firebase

Answer (score 3):

```
List<String>? categoriesList = (map['categories'] as List)?.cast<String>()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't actually work if you have 'implicit-dynamic' enabled.

It's also not easy to read.

A fully typed version of the conversion is:

```dart
List<String> categories = jsonToList(json['categories']);
```

Place the following functions in a helper library and you have a solution that is type safe, reusable and easy to read.

```dart
Set<T> jsonToSet<T>(Object? responseData) {
    final temp = responseData as List? ?? <dynamic>[];
    final set = <T>{};
    for (final tmp in temp) {
      set.add(tmp as T);
    }
    return set;
  }

  List<T> jsonToList<T>(Object? responseData) {
    final temp = responseData as List? ?? <dynamic>[];
    final list = <T>[];
    for (final tmp in temp) {
      list.add(tmp as T);
    }
    return list;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also utilize the global helper functions from the [Flutter Helper Utils package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_helper_utils).

```dart
categories = toList<String>(map['categories']);
```

or to avoid conflicts you can also use the static one.

```dart
categories = ConvertObject.toList<String>(map['categories']);
```

both static and global achieve the same behavior.

the package also handles differnt convertion types. [more details here](https://flutter-helper-utils.web.app/documentation/convert-object.html#available-methods)