# Dynamic Lists to String Lists

Tags: dart

I am getting data from my firestore, but I am only interested in the array part for this. I've prepared a dartpad for it:

https://dartpad.dev/9b99f0e2e8c83913f9cd2bd71bd70d81

How do I convert `List data = ['Room 1', 'Room 2'];` to `List<String> stringData = ['Room 1', 'Room 2'];`

There are similar questions, but I am probably too stupid to understand how the fix works, I tried to implement them but I think their input data looks a bit different. (like these: [How to cast <dynamic> to List<String>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60105956/how-to-cast-dynamic-to-liststring) or [How to Create DropdownButton with a list of JSON data within a list in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60419639/how-to-create-dropdownbutton-with-a-list-of-json-data-within-a-list-in-flutter))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`cast()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/cast.html):

```
List data = ['Room 1', 'Room 2'];

List<String> stringData;

void main() {
  stringData = data.cast<String>(); // <- look here
  print(stringData);
  print(data);
}
```

Comment: Other alternatives, where you create a new list instead of wrapping the existing one, are `stringData = [...data];`, `stringData = List.from(data);` or `stringData = data.whereType<String>().toList();` (in order of increasing clumsiness).